# What is the closest implementation of enum in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, enums

Many languages have enums as build in types.

I need to know what could be the closest implementation of enums in node with this syntax:

```
enum Types{
  TypeA,
  TypeB,
  TypeC,
}
```

I want to use it like this. (I do not want to assign value to each variable)

```
let x = Types.TypeA;

if(x == Types.TypeA){
   console.log('A')
}
if(x == Types.TypeB){
   console.log('B')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use Typescript for enum - bonus points if you want performance gains: use const enum :)

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html:

> Const enums can only use constant enum expressions and unlike regular enums they are completely removed during compilation. Const enum members are inlined at use sites. This is possible since const enums cannot have computed members.

```
const enum Direction {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}
 
let directions = [
  Direction.Up,
  Direction.Down,
  Direction.Left,
  Direction.Right,
];

in generated code will become

"use strict";
let directions = [
    0 /* Up */,
    1 /* Down */,
    2 /* Left */,
    3 /* Right */,
];
```

If you don't want to use Typescript (although I highly recommend it), I'm afraid you'll have to resort to an object:

```
const Types = {
  "TypeA": 0,
  "TypeB": 1,
  "TypeC": 2,
}
```